# Excel: Find rows with same id occurring within 30 days of each other

Tags: excel, merge, duplicates

I have a large excel table (25000 rows, 60 columns) with rows for each medical visit for 2000+ patients and then columns for type of visit, procedures, etc.

Each row has the illness ID [DxID], patient ID [ID], and the date of visit [DxDate].

Some patients have multiple rows/visits for the same illness. I need to count the number of illnesses in the cohort and by patient.

I have been able to identify visits on the same day by concatenating [ID] and [DxDate] and then using conditional formatting to find duplicates. I can then walk through those duplicates manually. However, I can't think of a formula that will identify rows with the same ID that occur within 30 days of each other (besides manually reading through all the rows of data).

I am happy to move the data into another database (access, R), but am still faced with the same problem.

Comment: Advanced filter should be sufficient but Power Query offers more latitude.

Comment: Have yo tried Pivot Tables to count the number of illnesses by patient?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a spreadsheet with the following columns:

```
A           ||  B           ||  C               ||  D               ||  E
PatientID   ||  IllnessID   ||  Date of Visit   ||  PatientIllness  ||  GroupID
```

(Your existing spreadsheet has columns A, B, and C; D and E are being added to get to the solution to your question.)

Row 1 is just column titles.

For **PatientIllness**, enter the following formula in cell D2:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,B2)
```

Then fill this all the way down the column.

Sort by **PatientIllness** ascending, **Date of Visit** ascending

In cell A2, type 1 (this is the first **GroupID**).

In cell A3, enter the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(D3=D2, DAYS(C3,C2) <31),E2,E2+1)
```

Then fill this all the way down the column.

Now rows with a matching **GroupID** are for patient/illness combinations that occurred within 30 days of each other (caveats below).

1. This won't work if you re-sort the data after creating the **GroupID**s (because they will recalculate, and that will be wrong).  If you need to sort the data after calculating **GroupID**, I'd suggest copying Column E, then pasting As Values (so you lose the formula, but you can resort and retain the correct **GroupID**s).
2. This approach assumes that groups are open-ended. So a **GroupID** is not just visit 1 and visit 2 that's within 30 days - if you have visit 1 on 1/1, visit 2 on 1/5, and visit 3 on 2/5, they all have the same **GroupID** (even though visit 1 and visit 3 are more than 30 days apart, they are connected through visit 2).  A **GroupID** doesn't change until either the **PatientIllness** value changes, or there is more than 30 days between visits.  I can't tell from your question whether this meets your business needs, but it is how every grouper I've ever worked with does things.
3. It's probably not worth it for a spreadsheet with only 25K rows, but I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that there are commercial software packages that do grouping like this - often with quite sophisticated rules about how to group things. For example, different time periods for chronic vs. acute care conditions, different ways to decide which visits get grouped together, etc. I don't work for anybody that makes those, and I'm not going to link to anybody, but if you search for 'healthcare data grouper' you'll find a few things out there.

Hope this helps.